# IcCube reporting V8 - How to reinitialize filters on a report?

Tags: iccube, iccube-reporting

Using reporting V7, I used to create a single button filter as following :

[image]

Then, for each filter I wanted to be reset on click on this button, I attributed this event on the "do Reset to initial selection"
[image]

How can I do this in V8 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had an answer from IcCube Support Team, they will add it in next release.